# How to replace duplicate questions/values in a row

Tags: r, replace, duplicates

I am about to spread a table, however I encountered a problem with my data. The data is based on a questionnaire, and the questions are in 1 column while the answers are in the next column. This data file contains about 20000 questionnaires, all pasted underneath each other.

It looks like this:

```
*Participant*   |      *Question*      |        *Answer* 
Paul            |    Age               |         15
Paul            |    City              |      Amsterdam
Paul            |    Pet_name          |       Butterfly
Paul            |    Fav_color         |       Pink
Paul            |    Parent_name       |       Hank
Paul            |    Parent_name       |       Mary
Adam            |    Age               |         78
Adam            |    City              |         LA
Adam            |    Pet_name          |       Crocodile
Adam            |    Fav_color         |       Purple
Adam            |    Parent_name       |       Pete
Adam            |    Parent_name       |       Peter
```

The problem is: I can't spread when 2 questions are called the same, in the case "Parent_name".

So preferably I'd like to replace the second occurrence of Parent_name, per Participant to be something like Parent2_name or Parent_name2

What I've tried to do is identify duplicated values with the `duplicated()` function, however, since all questions are repeated it will just flag everything from the second participant on as duplicated

To recreate my example data:

```
Participant <- c('Paul','Paul','Paul','Paul','Paul','Paul', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam' )
Question <- c('Age', 'City', 'Pet_name', 'Fav_color', 'Parent_name', 'Parent_name', 'Age', 'City', 'Pet_name', 'Fav_color', 'Parent_name', 'Parent_name')
Answer <- c('15', 'Amsterdam', 'Butterfly', 'Pink', 'Hank', 'Mary', '78', 'LA', 'Crocodile', 'Purple', 'Pete', 'Peter')

df <- data.frame(Participant, Question, Answer)
```

So the final product would look like:

```
*Participant*   |      *Question*      |        *Answer* 
Paul            |    Age               |         15
Paul            |    City              |      Amsterdam
Paul            |    Pet_name          |       Butterfly
Paul            |    Fav_color         |       Pink
Paul            |    Parent_name       |       Hank
Paul            |    Parent2_name      |       Mary
Adam            |    Age               |         78
Adam            |    City              |         LA
Adam            |    Pet_name          |       Crocodile
Adam            |    Fav_color         |       Purple
Adam            |    Parent_name       |       Pete
Adam            |    Parent2_name      |       Peter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `Participant` and `Question` and append the `row_number()` to `Question` if there is more than one row. This will work for any `Question` with duplicated values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Participant, Question) %>%
  mutate(Question1 = if (n() > 1) paste0(Question, row_number()) else Question) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-Question)

#   Participant Answer    Question1   
#   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>       
# 1 Paul        15        Age         
# 2 Paul        Amsterdam City        
# 3 Paul        Butterfly Pet_name    
# 4 Paul        Pink      Fav_color   
# 5 Paul        Hank      Parent_name1
# 6 Paul        Mary      Parent_name2
# 7 Adam        78        Age         
# 8 Adam        LA        City        
# 9 Adam        Crocodile Pet_name    
#10 Adam        Purple    Fav_color   
#11 Adam        Pete      Parent_name1
#12 Adam        Peter     Parent_name2
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Participant, Question, Answer, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey, this works on my Mock Data, however in my actual data I have a couple more columns that cause an error I think. 

I tried this code, based on your code:

group_by(Nummer, Leeftijd, Geslacht, Woonplaats, Datum, Vraag) %>%
  mutate(Vraag1 = if (n() > 1) paste0(Vraag, row_number()) else Question) 

And I get this error: 
Error: Column `Vraag1` must be length 1 (the group size), not 12
Sorry if the column names are in Dutch, I can translate if that makes it easier. All of these extra columns are like the Participant column btw, they repeat the values 6 times

Comment: @JolienJansen please add another example if there is a different part of your data causing an error. Column names in any language are fine - the content does not concern us as much as the structure.

Comment: @ cddt Will do that now

Comment: @JolienJansen Why are you grouping by other columns? Also is your column name `Vraag` or `Question` ?

Comment: Hey, So Question == Vraag in Dutch, so in my own Dataset the 'Question' column is called 'Vraag'. Even if I only group by 'Participant', in my own dataset it gives me the error "Error: Column `Vraag1` must be length 1 (the group size), not 12". I tried to recreate my own dataset as best as possible, but I only get the error on my own data, not the mock dataset. I am not sure what to recreate in my mock dataset to get the error, and it's not really possible to just post my own dataset on here. Not sure how to recreate the error now. Any ideas?

Comment: @JolienJansen In the attempt which you shared as a comment before you are using `mutate(Vraag1 = if (n() > 1) paste0(Vraag, row_number()) else Question)` but there is no `Question` in your data, right? Do you mean to use `mutate(Vraag1 = if (n() > 1) paste0(Vraag, row_number()) else Vraag)` ? Can you try that?

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, you are right.. That was the problem, I didn't translate it correctly. Thanks a lot for the help though

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
Participant <- c('Paul','Paul','Paul','Paul','Paul','Paul', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam', 'Adam' )
Question <- c('Age', 'City', 'Pet_name', 'Fav_color', 'Parent_name', 'Parent_name', 'Age', 'City', 'Pet_name', 'Fav_color', 'Parent_name', 'Parent_name')
Answer <- c('15', 'Amsterdam', 'Butterfly', 'Pink', 'Hank', 'Mary', '78', 'LA', 'Crocodile', 'Purple', 'Pete', 'Peter')

df <- data.table(Participant, Question, Answer)
```

Set a new column with an ID by participant and question, then join it to the original question where it is greater than two, and then remove the additional column.

```
df[, id := seq_len(.N), by = .(Participant, Question)]
df[id != 1, Question:= paste0(Question, id)]
df[, id := NULL]
```

Result:

```
> df
    Participant     Question    Answer
 1:        Paul          Age        15
 2:        Paul         City Amsterdam
 3:        Paul     Pet_name Butterfly
 4:        Paul    Fav_color      Pink
 5:        Paul  Parent_name      Hank
 6:        Paul Parent_name2      Mary
 7:        Adam          Age        78
 8:        Adam         City        LA
 9:        Adam     Pet_name Crocodile
10:        Adam    Fav_color    Purple
11:        Adam  Parent_name      Pete
12:        Adam Parent_name2     Peter
```

Comment: @JolienJansen I should mention that for large data sets, I expect a `data.table` solution to be faster than a `dplyr` one.

Comment: That is good to know, I've only recently started working with bigger data sets, so tips like those are definitely welcome.

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Question) %>%
  mutate(Index = rank(Question, ties.method = "first")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Question = paste(Question,Index, sep = "_")) %>%
  select(-Index) %>%
  spread(Question,Answer)
```

This uses rank to sequence the variables and should work no matter the number of duplicates or their order.